# Swift 3: Creating a custom TabBar with UICollectionView that segues to different controllers

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a collectionView inside of a UIView class that has 5 cells. It looks just like a TabBar but doing it via a collectionView, I will have the ability to customise it to my hearts content, right? I have this menuBar set up inside my appDelegate so it will be on top of every view. The issue I have is that inside of my collectionView, I am not able to call this inside a UIView:

```
present(viewController), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I would call this inside the didSelectItemAt method and check if the indexPath.item is == 0, segue to the first controller but I cannot seem to figure out a solution on how to do this... Here is my code. Any help would be highly appreciated and of course, marked as answer. Cheers.

App Delegate:

```
    var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DummyController())

    let menuBar: MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        return mb
    }()

    window?.addSubview(menuBar)

    _ = menuBar.anchor(nil, left: window?.leftAnchor, bottom: window?.bottomAnchor, right: window?.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 50)

    return true
}
```

MenuBar Class (custom tab bar):

```
class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    return cv
}()

let seperatorView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = lightGray
    return view
}()

let imageNames = ["home_selected", "glimpse_selected", "camera_selected", "activity_selected", "profile_selected"]

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(collectionView)
    addSubview(seperatorView)

    collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

    _ = collectionView.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    _ = seperatorView.anchor(collectionView.topAnchor, left: collectionView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: collectionView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 1)

    setupHorizontalBar()
}

var horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func setupHorizontalBar() {
    let horizontalBarView = UIView()
    horizontalBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    horizontalBarView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    addSubview(horizontalBarView)

    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint = horizontalBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor)
    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true

    horizontalBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    horizontalBarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/5).isActive = true
    horizontalBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4).isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        // segue
    }

    let x = CGFloat(indexPath.item) * frame.width / 5
    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant = x

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[indexPath.item])?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 5, height: self.frame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: I have sometimes added a custom view as a tab bar replacement, but usually I used to do like this: **1**. Create a RootViewController which will be the displaying area for all the tab controllers. **2**. Set up custom view with menu items in root in bottom or as desired **3**. Set up delegate between custom view and root view controller for tap events. **4**. When tap is received add new view controller as sub view of root view controller where we have a placeholder for tab bar controller. Animate if required

Comment: @Jimmy Try this code UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

You can't present a UIViewController from a UIView(or any other non controller classes) class. But you can add it as a subview.
To present or push a UIViewcontroller, you have to do it from a class of UIViewController type.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, you could use a call back

```
var cellWithIndexSelected : ((IndexPath) -> Void)?
```

then in your AppDelegate you could attach some function to it

```
menuBar.cellWithIndexSelected = { someIndex in
   window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SomeOtherViewController())
}
```

then in your didSelectItemAt method you'd have this

```
if indexPath.item == 1 {
// segue
   cellWithIndexSelected(indexPath)       
}
```

You could use NotificationCenter or you might be able to use a protocol delegate pattern.

These would work but generally you should have a parent view controller that holds this tab bar and handle these presentations outside of your app delegate.